# Getting cpu usage by process within container with limits

Tags: java

Do you know whether exist a library for Java that makes it possible to get recent CPU usage, let's say for the last few seconds?

This library should work on different OSes (Mac, Linux, Windows) and be container-aware - let's say that our JVM was run in container and CPU was limited to 1000 ticks per any period. Then, cpu usage by process should be relative to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

With Jmx / MBean you can get that kind of info. Java process will run as fast as the CPU limit. So that measurement doesn't make sense on different machine.

To have an idea you need to develop on docker with CPU limits and check wall clock to validate requirement of the service with load tests like gatling https://gatling.io/.